# Twisted: cache list of instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted

I am currently working through the twisted Developer Guides and would like to get some information/guide regarding extending the usecase of one of the provides examples, namely caching instances of objects:

The example code is:

cache.classes.py

```
from twisted.spread import pb

class MasterDuckPond(pb.Cacheable):
    def __init__(self, ducks):
        self.observers = []
        self.ducks = ducks

    def count(self):
        print "I have [%d] ducks" % len(self.ducks)

    def addDuck(self, duck):
        self.ducks.append(duck)
        for o in self.observers: o.callRemote('addDuck', duck)

    def removeDuck(self, duck):
        self.ducks.remove(duck)
        for o in self.observers: o.callRemote('removeDuck', duck)

    def getStateToCacheAndObserveFor(self, perspective, observer):
        self.observers.append(observer)
# you should ignore pb.Cacheable-specific state, like self.observers
        return self.ducks # in this case, just a list of ducks

    def stoppedObserving(self, perspective, observer):
        self.observers.remove(observer)

class SlaveDuckPond(pb.RemoteCache):
    # This is a cache of a remote MasterDuckPond

    def count(self):
        return len(self.cacheducks)

    def getDucks(self):
        return self.cacheducks

    def setCopyableState(self, state):
        print " cache - sitting, er, setting ducks"
        self.cacheducks = state

    def observe_addDuck(self, newDuck):
        print " cache - addDuck"
        self.cacheducks.append(newDuck)

    def observe_removeDuck(self, deadDuck):
        print " cache - removeDuck"
        self.cacheducks.remove(deadDuck)
pb.setUnjellyableForClass(MasterDuckPond, SlaveDuckPond)
```

cache_sender.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

from twisted.spread import pb, jelly
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor
from cache_classes import MasterDuckPond

class Sender:
    def __init__(self, pond):
        self.pond = pond

    def phase1(self, remote):
        self.remote = remote
        d = remote.callRemote("takePond", self.pond)
        d.addCallback(self.phase2).addErrback(log.err)

    def phase2(self, response):
        self.pond.addDuck("ugly duckling")
        self.pond.count()
        reactor.callLater(1, self.phase3)

    def phase3(self):
        d = self.remote.callRemote("checkDucks")
        d.addCallback(self.phase4).addErrback(log.err)

    def phase4(self, dummy):
        self.pond.removeDuck("one duck")
        self.pond.count()
        self.remote.callRemote("checkDucks")
        d = self.remote.callRemote("ignorePond")
        d.addCallback(self.phase5)

    def phase5(self, dummy):
        d = self.remote.callRemote("shutdown")
        d.addCallback(self.phase6)

    def phase6(self, dummy):
        reactor.stop()

    def main():
        master = MasterDuckPond(["one duck", "two duck"])
        master.count()
        sender = Sender(master)
        factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
        reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8800, factory)
        deferred = factory.getRootObject()
        deferred.addCallback(sender.phase1)
        reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

cache_receiver.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

from twisted.application import service, internet
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.spread import pb
import cache_classes

class Receiver(pb.Root):
    def remote_takePond(self, pond):
        self.pond = pond
        print "got pond:", pond # a DuckPondCache
        self.remote_checkDucks()

    def remote_checkDucks(self):
        print "[%d] ducks: " % self.pond.count(), self.pond.getDucks()

    def remote_ignorePond(self):
        # stop watching the pond
        print "dropping pond"
        # gc causes __del__ causes 'decache' msg causes stoppedObserving
        self.pond = None

    def remote_shutdown(self):
        reactor.stop()
application = service.Application("copy_receiver")
internet.TCPServer(8800, pb.PBServerFactory(Receiver())).setServiceParent(
service.IServiceCollection(application))
```

This example seems pretty straightforward, the MasterDuckPond is controlled by the sending side, and the SlaveDuckPond is a cache that tracks changes to the master.

However, how would I go about updating/caching an entire list of instanced objects?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use PB.  The protocol is overly complicated for at least 99% of use-cases (meaning you will have to work a lot harder than necessary to understand, implement, and maintain your project).  There are no other implementations of it and there probably never will be (which means you're stuck with Python and Twisted - which is not to say those things are bad, but there are a lot of other things out there that may also be good).  The level of maintenance is minimal (so if you find bugs, there's a small chance someone will help you get them fixed but that's about all you can expect - and you may not even get that if the bugs aren't trivial).

Give HTTP a try.  It can do a lot.  If you combine it with a data format like Capn, CBOR, or even JSON it can do even more.

Comment: Thank your for your reply, however, I am not looking specifically into PB, this is just one example given in the twisted developer guideline that I wanted some further information for.

Comment: Okay, glad to hear it.  I'm not sure how to answer your question in a way that generalizes beyond PB though.  I think it is strictly a question about the features and usage of PB.  So I suppose I'll stand by my answer (or non-answer, if you like).

Comment: As I am just looking for a solution specific to this example I would not mind an answer that just fits PB or even just this very example, as otherwise I would tinker around myself. Thank you for your answer nevertheless, I will think twice before using PB in any real application.